# How do I find the number of ways to place blocks of length 1 and 3, in a walkway, using recursion?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have been given the following problem. Given a walkway of length n, design a recursive algorithm that tells the number of ways to place blocks of size 1 and size 3 on the walkway. I understand the strategy to apply recursion to this problem -

1. Put in base cases for cases where the walkway is of lengths 1, 2, and 3.
2. Assume that you already have figured out the number of ways to place blocks of length 1 on the walkway
3. Assume that you already have figured out the number of ways to place blocks of length 3 on the walkway
4. Add 2) and 3)

My problem is that I don't know how to code 2) and 3). Here's my code below -

```
def countPatterns(n):
    if(n==1 or n==2):
        return 1
    elif(n==3):
        return 2
    elif(n<1):
        return 0
    else:
       # return 2) and 3)
```

Comment: This sounds like a problem from https://projecteuler.net/ !

Comment: Also, I think the strategy that you described is not correct. You appear to assume that (number of ways to place blocks of lengths 1 and 3) = (number of ways to place blocks of length 1) + (number of ways to place blocks of length 3). But that's not true.

Comment: It's more like: (number of ways to place blocks of lengths 1 and 3 on a walkway of length n) = (number of ways to place blocks of lengths 1 and 3 on a walkway of length n-1) + (number of ways to place blocks of lengths 1 and 3 on a walkway of length n-3)

Comment: Also, if n == 0, then you should return 1, not 0. Only if n < 0 you should return 0.

Comment: @Stef "(number of ways to place blocks of lengths 1 and 3 on a walkway of length n-1) + (number of ways to place blocks of lengths 1 and 3 on a walkway of length n-3)". Could you please explain why are we taking (n-1) and (n-3). I am unable to wrap my head around it.

Comment: there are two types of walkways of length n: those that start with a length-1 block and those that start with a length-3 block. the number of walkways of length n that start with a length-1 block is equal to the number of walkways of length n-1 (because you only need to choose how to tile the remaining n-1 spaces). The number of walkways of length n that start with a length-3 block is equal to the number of walkways of length n-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is the same as **given the target sum and you need to count number of ways that you can get that target sum just by adding numbers 1 and 3.**
Example:

```
sum = 4
ways:
  1: 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
  2: 1 + 3
  3: 3 + 1
So your function for sum = 4 should return 3.
```

I think your approach is wrong. Here is my solution:

```
def numWays(tSum):
    if tSum < 0:
        return 0
    if tSum <= 2:
        return 1
    return numWays(tSum - 1) + numWays(tSum - 3)
```